# Block access to php.ini file

Tags: php, security, apache

We have a custom php.ini and .htaccess file in the root of the web tree.

The .htaccess cannot be accessed by default but the php.ini can be accessed.

For example:

```
http://example.com/php.ini
```

Whats the recommenced procedure to block access to the php.ini file?

Comment: does it have to be in the web folder? Can you place it outside the scope of the public folder? If you have multiple websites you can always set it up like site1, then site1/public_html. Where site1 is the website and public_html is setup to be the root. then you can place php.ini in the site1 folder if you want to.

Comment: this, and would a 644 chmod suffice?

Comment: @Matt No. It has to reside in the web folder. Maybe change location within the folder?

Comment: @zaf look at my update. You can have the public folder as a sub folder maybe?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Also if you must have it in the public folder try:

```
<Files php.ini>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Cool - that seems to work. Can I add that anywhere in .htaccess file or it has to be the first thing?

Comment: @zaf no you can add it anywhere. It should parse it when it sees it.

Answer (score -2):

Change the CHMOD or permissions so it is not executable by the user.