# How can I protect a credentials file using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am working on an old project.

The database credentials are stored as JSON in web root in a file like .my_secret and configurations are stored in .my_config - A PHP script reads these files and uses the data for connecting to the database and retrieving other settings.

If someone tries to access this file, I want to throw a 404 error, file not found.

How can I do this using only `.htaccess`? I don't want to use `.htpasswd`

I tried to move the files outside the web root, but I encountered an `open_basedir restriction in effect`

Comment: Instead of trying to block access to individual files you should follow the general best practice to route each and every request through a single router script. So that you can simply rewrite _all_ incoming requests through that script. Even if you then add exceptions for static resources like icons and style sheets you still have a robust solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block access to php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225765/block-access-to-php-ini-file)

Comment: To clarify what arkascha is suggesting, you should move that JSON file *out of your web root so that it cannot be accessed directly by http request*. If open_basedir is causing trouble, I'd strongly recommend reconfiguring your server, if you can.

Comment: It's a shared hosting, I can't reconfigure my web server. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a rewrite rule for these files that points to a 404 file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^(\.my_config|\.my_secret) 404.php [L,nc]
```

In the 404.php file you can output 404 headers like this:

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

Comment: @marjia. This works only for as long as those two lines are present in the .htaccess file and no mistakes are made. From experience I know this can go wrong. The fail save way to protect these files is to put them outside the web root, so the webserver will just never serve them.

Comment: I know, it's a small project, I wanted a fast solution.